# how to print all rows of csv files if condition is true

Tags: python, csv

i have multiple csv files in my directory, all csv files have "Date & Time" row 
Date & Time Format in Row is Like This: 01PM&13-02-2019.

i want when someone put whatever date record he wants my function return all csv files data
Now its just giving me one column data.

```
from csv import DictReader
import os
class Show:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def today(self):
        for fn in os.listdir("F:\Python_Folder"):
            if ".csv" in fn:
                with open(fn,'r') as s_read:
                    data = DictReader(s_read, delimiter=',')
                    for i in data:
                        d1 = i['Date & Time']
                        d2= d1.split('&')
                        if d2[0] =='13-02-2019':
                            print(f"{i['Name']} {i['Email']} {i['Mobile']} {i['Service Type']} {i['Date & Time']} {i['Address']} {i['Message']} ")
```

right now i have already written date, later i will add input there

My .csv file

[image]

Comment: what it should show ? its just an object. real thing is happening after this line, where DictReader is reading files

Comment: In your example time stamp daytime comes before date, but you call the zeroth element of the time stamp in your condition before printing - instead of the first element.

Comment: @SvenKrüger how ? can you explain more, because "i"  has all object values thats's why i split it

Comment: Consider this: `d2 = '01PM&13-02-2019'.split('&')` results in `d2 = ('01PM', '13-02-2019')`... Thus `d2[0] == '1PM'` will return the daytime instead of the date.

Comment: @SvenKrüger if i try this d2[1], its showing error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Then the format of `i['Date & Time']` does not correspond to your example `'01PM&13-02-2019'`.

Comment: @SvenKrüger Date & Time is a row name which is in my .csv file not in my code

Comment: `i['Date & Time']` is  a complete statement and it holds a value. This value does not fit to the format of your example... Can you simply show an excerpt of one of your CSV-files? Maybe the first five to ten rows?... You should also put the output here that is actually printed and in comparison show what the desired output should look like.

Comment: @SvenKrüger question updated, remember i have one column in which i have date&time that's am splitting data with &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os, csv
csvfiles = []
for fn in os.listdir("F:\Python_Folder"):
    if fn.endswith('.csv'): 
        csvfiles.append(str(fn))
if len(csvfiles) == 0:
    print("no csv files")
else:
    yourdate = "01PM&13-02-2019"
    yourtime = yourdate.split('&')[1]
    flag = false
    for csv_file_name in csvfiles:
        with open(csv_file_name) as csv_file:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                if yourtime in row:
                    print('Name','Email','Mobile','Service Type','Date & time','Address','Message')
                    for data in row:
                        print(data,end=" ")
                    flag = true
        if flag:
            break
```

Comment: appreciate your effort but sorry you didn't get my question.

Comment: Now I have made a change, check that.

Comment: You said you wanted to check if csv file exists in the directory and also you cannot read the csv files correctly. I have given the right solution. Only you know when the user will enter the date. Put my code inside a method and call the method when the user enters some date.

Comment: actually your code is printing those line which is here  if line == 1: ,  in my code i am trying to get all data which is === mydate,                         d1 = i['Date & Time']
                        d2= d1.split('&')
                        if d2[0] =='13-02-2019':

Comment: Did you check now?

Comment: its showing your this line has some error "                 csvfiles.append(str(file)) undefined variable

Comment: Check now, i that was a typo

Comment: its working thank u so much, god bless u,

Comment: This is my first accepted answer. Thank you @Cathrine